# No virtual channel available for quarkus test amazon lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, quarkus

I created a simple quarkus lambda rest  project as described in the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http)

```
mvn archetype:generate \
       -DarchetypeGroupId=io.quarkus \
       -DarchetypeArtifactId=quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest-archetype \
       -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1.Final
```

I only kept the JAXRS stuff with the following resource:

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello jaxrs";
    }
}
```

I then tried to add an integration test as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda#integration-testing) by first adding the lambda test dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-test-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I then added the `application.properties` as described containing `quarkus.lambda.enable-polling-jvm-mode=true`.

Finally, I added a simple test case:

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class GreetingTest
{
    @Test
    public void testSimpleLambdaSuccess() {
        InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(
                GreetingTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/request.json")
        );

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        LambdaClient.invoke(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
}
```

The `request.json` file is an event I generated using `sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy` and just fixed the path to match my resource (although this has no effect on the following issue).

When I run the test however, I always get the following error:

```
2021-08-31 17:09:10,108 WARN  [io.net.res.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) Can not find io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider in the classpath, fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS.
2021-08-31 17:09:10,604 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 2.2.1.Final on JVM started in 1.867s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081
2021-08-31 17:09:10,604 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated. 
2021-08-31 17:09:10,604 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [amazon-lambda, cdi, resteasy, security, smallrye-context-propagation]
2021-08-31 17:09:10,960 ERROR [qua.ama.lam.http] (Lambda Thread) Request Failure: java.lang.RuntimeException: No virtual channel available
    at io.quarkus.netty.runtime.virtual.VirtualClientConnection.connect(VirtualClientConnection.java:113)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.nettyDispatch(LambdaHttpHandler.java:204)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHttpHandler.java:61)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHttpHandler.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaRecorder$1.processRequest(AmazonLambdaRecorder.java:155)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AbstractLambdaPollLoop$1.run(AbstractLambdaPollLoop.java:80)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

{"statusCode":500,"multiValueHeaders":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"body":"{ \"message\": \"Internal Server Error\" }","isBase64Encoded":false}
```

I tried to debug a little bit through the stack trace and it looks like there is actually no netty virtual channel registered.

Am I missing something to initialise netty virtual channels or am I doing something wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I also tried adding `netty-resolver-dns-native-macos` to get rid of this dns warning, but this doesn't change anything (apart from the warning no longer being shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the quarkus sources, I found a similar integration test example. After comparing this with my code I found one difference in the `application.properties`:

```properties
quarkus.http.virtual=true
```

There is even a [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.virtual) on this flag:

> quarkus.http.virtual
>
> If this is true then only a virtual channel will be set up for vertx web. We have this switch for testing purposes.

After enabling this flag, everything started to work as expected! Maybe it would have been helpful to have a reference to this flag from the documentation on quarkus testing.